# WP site with huge database issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, database-design

We have news portal site and it's a 15years site old site. We have plugin and WP updated, due to which it has huge database. So,sometime Mysql get's down and when we load it covers huge cpanel's cpu, which cross 100 and hit over site gets huge.so how can we solve this problem,is there any way of optimizing database or site so that when we hit site url it hits low cup space of cpanel

Comment: For database optimization you should try [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). They will still want focused questions backed up with lots of specific details.

Comment: One speedup for many WP sites is http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of things that you can do to optimize your database, but first of all **make a debug**.

Next,

- in mysql you have the possibility to optimize table
- wordpress has tons of plugins that may help you (https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/search/optimize+database/)
- you can manually delete unused content/user/media/plugin (for plugin make sure to select "delete data" options if exist)

Here you can find an article that help you:
https://cultofweb.com/blog/reduce-the-size-of-your-wordpress-database/

Good luck!

Comment: and after researching i found out that database replication / sharding is also the possible way. So can you clear me replication / sharding is also a better method or what

Comment: I think that depends of your problem, at first it's better to optimize the database mostly if you looking into replication / sharding. Next if your problems it's caused by a great quantity of user and the consequences of great number of concurrent connection replication / sharding maybe are a good approach to speed up the database.

Comment: obviously replication / sharding make your db administration operation more complex, think well before to move forward in this direction.